# Can't get percentages to work in CSS with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So I'm trying to create a card with information on the right and a purple hue on the left if it's selected. I'm using Next and TailwindCSS.

Here is my parent component which renders the cards:

```js
{files ? (
  <div className="ml-6 mt-8 absolute">
    {files.map((value) => {
      return <FileCard key={value.id} file={value} />
    })}
  </div>
) : (
  <div>graphql not working :(</div>
)}
```

and here is the FileCard component:

```js
return (
    <div className="flex justify-content items-center mb-4 w-72 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg relative">
        <div className="h-full w-2 bg-indigo-600 relative rounded-l-lg"></div> <- // here the h-full not working
        <div className="py-4 px-4 flex justify-between items-center">
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center align-start text-sm font-bold">
                <p>{file.title}</p>
                <p className="text-xs">Last updated: {date.toString()}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Expected results:

[image: Expected Results]

Actual results:

[image: Actual results]

If I hard code the height with `h-20`:

[image: If I hard code the height with h-20]

Answer (score 2):

You can use vh. Example: h-[40vh].

Answer (score 0):

As described in the official tailwindcss [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height#full-height)

> Use h-full to set an element's height to 100% of its parent, as long as the parent has a defined height.

100% height only works if the parent element has a fixed height defined.

So one of the possible solution is to set the height of parent element like:

```
<div className="h-20 flex justify-content items-center mb-4 w-72 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg relative">
```

Here i've set the height to 20 which is equivalent to 5rem. You can set it according to your need and the inner div will adapt to that height if h-full is applied to it.

Comment: Well the goal wasn't to hard code a value. Like I described in my question, I did try that.

Comment: It's a CSS property, % units only work when the parent element have a corresponding property defined. There's no workaround to it.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late in the party but have you tried passing a percentage like this:

```
<div className="w-full h-[40%]">
```

You would notice in the web inspector, it creates a class like this on the fly:

```
.h-\[40\%\] {
height: 40%;
```

}

There is no need to extend in the tailwind config.

This works for everything in the framework, including things like background colors, font sizes, pseudo-element content, and more.

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

Comment: h-[40%] doesn't work